# Problema para mostrar correctamente datos de una consulta

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo cuatro tablas: Users, Profiles, Cities y Ads.

Hago una consulta y me muestra solo los anuncios (Ads) que se hayan publicado y que también hayan completado el perfil, si el usuario no ha completado el perfil no me lo muestra, necesito que los muestre así el usuario no tenga el perfil completado.

Mi tabla users en la migración:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('city_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('phone')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Mi tabla Profiles en la migración:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('profession_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('profession_id')->references('id')->on('professions');
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('photo')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Mi tabla Cities en la migración:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('province_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('province_id')->references('id')->on('provinces');
        $table->string('city', 35);
    });
}
```

Mi tabla Ads en la migración:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('ads', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('status')->default('DRAFT');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Las tengo relacionadas de la siguiente manera:

Model User:

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
} 

public function profile()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Profile::class);
}

public function ads()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Ad::class);
}
```

Model Profile:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
} 

public function profession()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Profession::class);
} 

public function ads()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Ad::class);
}
```

Model City:

```
public function province()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Province::class);
}
```

Model user

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
} 

public function profile()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Profile::class);
}

public function ads()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Ad::class);
}
```

Mi consulta en el controlador:

```
public function index()
{

    $ads = Ad::where("status", 'PUBLISHED')
                    ->join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'ads.user_id')
                    ->orderBy('ads.id', 'DESC')
                    ->paginate(12);


    return  view('web/users/listing', compact('ads'));

}
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Para qué haces un join con la tabla profiles si dices que no importa si está o no dicha información?

Comment: Necesito obtener el campo photo de profile, en caso que el usuario haya completado el perfil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que tienes los modelos creados en Eloquent con sus respectivas relaciones, puedes utilizar esta herramienta para obtener lo que necesitas, también con la ayuda de Eager Loading para cargar la relación de user y profile:

```
$ads = Ad::with('user.profile')
           ->whereStatus('PUBLISHED')
           ->orderBy('ads.id', 'DESC')
           ->paginate(12);
```

Estoy asumiendo que hay una relación entre Ad y User, y otra relación entre User y Profile.

Por último, para obtener el campo photo de profile, sería con la siguiente sintaxis, después de iterar:

```
$photo = optional($ad->user->profile)->photo;
```

Con el helper optional, obtendrás null cuando no haya un profile asociado.

Comment: Voy a intentarlo, ->whereStatus('PUBLISHED') aplica solo para Ads, correcto?

Comment: En este caso sí, a menos que el campo lo tengas en otras tablas también.

Comment: No, solo lo tengo en Ads... Creo tener las relaciones bien, voy a revisar porque no me toma profile: $ad->user->profile->photo;

Comment: Revisa la edición que hice, para que no arroje error cuando no hay un profile asociado en la base de datos.

Comment: Revisé: Eager Loading y creo tenerlo bien, solo había publicado mal las relaciones del modelo User, ya la edite en la pregunta. Aún no lo logro

Comment: La relación Profile en la colección se muestra NULL

Comment: No veo en el código que muestras el modelo Profile

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta nuevamente

Comment: Alguna otra sugerencia @Shaz estoy perdido.

Comment: Yo veo todo bien en mi respuesta, es posible que falte información que nos debas mostrar para entender el problema o lo que no funciona.

Comment: No dudo que tu respuesta esté bien, yo soy el que está haciendo algo mal, quizás el tema de Eager Loading que lo desconozco

Comment: Considero que el problema planteado ya fue solucionado: Mostrar los anuncios publicados, sin importar si los usuarios tienen un perfil asociado o no. El problema de la relación que no te funciona, es un asunto distinto, que requiere un análisis detallado, digno de una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Gracias Shaz, muy amable.